# python resolve redirection URLs

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I use requests to solve twitter urls, it works for all valid URLs, but if the URL cant be resolved, the variable `r` will get me the the input value as response. If I copy the URL into a browser I it wont get loaded, but the url will be resolved.

Is there a method, to resolve redirection URLs, also when the target-url can't get loaded.

```
def unshortenTwitterURL(url):
  try:
    r = requests.head(url, allow_redirects=True, timeout=10)
    res = r.url
  except:
    res = url
  return res
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not allow redirects. And then look at `r.headers['location']`.